# c++ const_cast from type ‘const BIGNUM*’ to type ‘BIGNUM**’

Tags: c++

I am getting error during const_cast

```
KeyPair.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool KeyPairImpl::setKeyField(const std::string&, const std::string&)’:
KeyPair.cpp:188: error: invalid const_cast from type ‘const BIGNUM*’ to type ‘BIGNUM**’
```

```
bool KeyPairImpl::setKeyField(const string &field, const string &value)
{
  BIGNUM **f = const_cast<BIGNUM **>(getField(field));

  if (!f)
    return false;

  // translate binary to bignum
  *f = BN_bin2bn((const unsigned char *)&value[0], value.length(), *f);

  return true;
}
```

I believe the issue happened after I did change in below function.

```
const BIGNUM *KeyPairImpl::getField(const string &field) const
{
  if (field == "P")
    return DSA_get0_p(dsa_);
  else if (field == "Q")
    return DSA_get0_q(dsa_);
  else if (field == "G")
    return DSA_get0_g(dsa_);
  else if (field == "X")
    return DSA_get0_priv_key(dsa_);
  else if (field == "Y")
    return DSA_get0_pub_key(dsa_);
  else
    // unknown field name
    return NULL;
}
```

The change which I did in the above code is as below

```
Before: const BIGNUM * const *KeyPairImpl::getField(const string &field) const
After : const BIGNUM *KeyPairImpl::getField(const string &field) const
```

Please suggest me how do I modify setKeyField method correctly.

Comment: A `const BIGNUM*` is *not* a `BIGNUM**`. How would you ever expect such a cast to be meaningful? Also; stop using C-style casts - they are dangerous/error prone.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? Clearly there are many things wrong with converting `const BIGNUM *` to `BIGNUM **` but it's so strange it's hard to guess what you actually meant to do.

Comment: Side note: Are you absolutely certain you want to cast away `const`? This can lead to a hard-to-detect case of [The Bads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). Don't do this just to eliminate a compiler error. Be absolutely certain.

Comment: `return NULL;` - we don't live in C++98 land any more, use `return nullptr;`.

Comment: @Kalpesh Tawde Which signature is correct, Before or After?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of `setKeyField()` is all wrong.

`getField()` returns a `const BIGNUM *`, ie a pointer to a const `BIGNUM`, but you are trying to cast that into a pointer-to-pointer-to-`BIGNUM`, which is not the same thing.  That is why the compiler complains about an invalid cast.

You are trying to give `BN_bin2bn()` a non-NULL pointer to a `BIGNUM` for it to write to.  On success, `BN_bin2bn()` will return a pointer to the same `BIGNUM`, and on failure it will return NULL.  If `BN_bin2bn()` fails, (ie, the input `value` contains invalid data, etc), you don't want to write a NULL back into your original field (which you can't do anyway).  So don't try to assign the *return value* of `BN_bin2bn()` back to `f`, its *`ret` parameter* will handle that.  Use the *return value* only for error handling.

Also, you are not taking into account the possibility of `value` being empty.  Accessing index 0 of an empty `std::string` is *undefined behavior* prior to C++11.

Try this instead:

```cpp
bool KeyPairImpl::setKeyField(const string &field, const string &value)
{
  const BIGNUM *f = getField(field);
  if (!f)
    return false;

  // translate binary to bignum
  return BN_bin2bn(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(value.c_str()), value.length(), const_cast<BIGNUM*>(f));

  /* alternatively, to avoid any possibility of corrupting
     your field data if BN_bin2bn() happens to fail part-way
     through its parsing...

  BIGNUM *num = BN_bin2bn(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(value.c_str()), value.length(), NULL);
  if (!num)
    return false;

  BN_copy(const_cast<BIGNUM*>(f), num);
  BN_free(num);

  return true;
  */
}
```

I might suggest taking this a step further by declaring and using a non-const overload of `getField()` to handle the casting:

```cpp
const BIGNUM* KeyPairImpl::getField(const string &field) const
{
  if (field == "P")
    return DSA_get0_p(dsa_);
  else if (field == "Q")
    return DSA_get0_q(dsa_);
  else if (field == "G")
    return DSA_get0_g(dsa_);
  else if (field == "X")
    return DSA_get0_priv_key(dsa_);
  else if (field == "Y")
    return DSA_get0_pub_key(dsa_);
  else
    // unknown field name
    return NULL;
}

BIGNUM* KeyPairImpl::getField(const string &field)
{
    const KeyPairImpl &cThis = *this;
    return const_cast<BIGNUM*>(cThis.getField(field));
}

bool KeyPairImpl::setKeyField(const string &field, const string &value)
{
  BIGNUM *f = getField(field);
  if (!f)
    return false;

  // translate binary to bignum
  return BN_bin2bn(..., f);

  /* alternatively:
  BIGNUM *num = BN_bin2bn(..., NULL);
  ...
  BN_copy(f, num);
  ...
  */
}
```